# How to get this video to show/play in the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, embed

I was wondering how to get the following code to work. There is a youtube video in the television but I can't get it to show up or play. I was wondering what the solution to this would be? Thanks!

```css
.tv {
    position: relative;
}


.tv img {
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 550px;
}

.video {
position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}

.b {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tv">
  <img src="http://honeypotmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/OLD-SCHOOL-TV.png" alt="" />
  
  <div class="video">
      <iframe class="b" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NJ_0Apc7r7A" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use code as below in `iframe`

Add `?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1` to `src` of video to **autoplay**:

```
<iframe class="b" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NJ_0Apc7r7A?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1"  frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[**Working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq27ohgj/)

**Edit to your comment!**

> I do not want autoplay. When I take autoplay off, the video will not
>   play

Use [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to `.video`

[**Working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq27ohgj/1/)

**If you want Round edges** to video use:

```
.video {
position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index:10;
  border: 4px solid #000;
   border-radius: 15px;
}
```

[**Working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq27ohgj/2/)

Comment: I do not want autoplay. When I take autoplay off, the video will not play

Comment: Thank you! The only problem with this is that it doesn't work for mobile view?

Comment: In mobile view, the video is too big so it goes outside over the tv image.

Comment: use `media-query` to set other width/height  in mobile :https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

This code is very simple and understandable with a little CSS knowledge
In this code, we have a picture in a div tag called "tv" with the position of the tag "relative"
And there's an "iframe" code snippet in the code that we can add to the content of a site within a site.
Now after we have placed the "iframe" in the code, we give it the "position: absolute" in the CSS, which is to do this so that the tag will be placed as the child "" And it's easy to identify the location of the film on the television with the "top left top right" attribitions.

The following links can help you:

[positioning in css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

[iframe tag html](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Answer (score 0):

please remove position: absolute; Then Run Your Code

Comment: When I remove it, the video is no longer inside the tv image.

Comment: Then you Remove It Then Minimize Video Size And Adjust z-index value

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the image of the TV is sitting over the YouTube video, so there is a layer blocking the user from clicking the play button. I would suggest moving the `div class="video"` forward one by adding `z-index:11` to its CSS.

Also, as far as I know videos are [no longer allowed to just auto-play](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), unless muted.